# Finding a solution for k-means in 1-dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, optimization, k-means

Given are three points in 1-dimensional space: $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 2$ and $x_3 = 3$.
We want to calculate the global minimizer for the objective function of k-means with k=1 (It is also added in the exercise to consider that if at any iteration no point is assigned to some center $µ_j$ ,this center is not updated during that iteration).

I know that the objective function of k-means is $$\text{argmin}_S \sum_i |S_i|* Var( S_i)$$

with $S_i$ being the clusters. My approach would be:

differentiate $||\mu||^2+||\mu-2||^2+||\mu-3||^2$ with respect to $\mu$. This gives me $\mu = 10/6$. This seems to be the average of the three points.

Any feedback on my approach being correct? Thanks

Comment: that looks right, but I also didn't take any class about this. I think the average is the mean part of k-means. If you put every point into a single cluster, k means gives a centroid that is at the local minimum. Your differentiation shows that there is only one local minimum in this case, and there is no edge points to count. So that has to be the global minimum of the objective function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution for the cluster centroid is correct, and your approach is fine for this particular toy problem with $k=1$. The way your objective function is written, a solution would take the form of an assignment of points to clusters (which is trivially a single cluster containing all points, since $k=1$).

Keep in mind that you wont' be able to solve k-means this way in general. The k-means problem is NP-hard, so an algorithm that can find a global minimum in the general case in a feasible amount of time probably doesn't exist. In practice, k-means algorithms find approximate solutions that are local minima.

Comment: Finally an answer, thank you SO much:-) I took the objective function from wikipedia. I knew about k-means being NP hard, and I was actually wondering how to solve the following for exact same data: "For k = 3, what is a global minimizer of the k-means objective?" - do you have any suggestions? It seems to me that this is also trivial, I could set the means to the points themselves, then the Variances would be 0, hence we would actually have a minimization of the objective function. It is an old exam question and I really wonder if it would be so trivial or if I am missing something

Comment: Yep, that's right for k=3. There are 3 possible solutions (i.e. 3 ways to assign each point to its own cluster), but they only ask for one. I'm as surprised as you are that it's an exam question.